# Proguard and apache legacy

Tags: java, android, gradle, proguard, android-apache-legacy

I'm using `Android API 23` and `org.apache.http.legacy` so I can use `Volley`. Everything works except when I use `proguard`. I'm getting this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:packageDevRelease'. Unable to
>   compute hash of
>   ...app/build/intermediates/classes-proguard/dev/release/classes.jar

My gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.jakewharton.hugo:hugo-plugin:1.2.1'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "..."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 3
        versionName "1.0.0"
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/services/javax.annotation.processing.Processor'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        ...
    }

    productFlavors {
        ...
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/org.apache.http.legacy.jar')

    // #### Submodules
    compile project(':submodules:volley')

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:percent:23.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'

    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.4.0'

    compile "com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar"
    compile 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.5.2@aar'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.viewpagerindicator:library:2.4.1@aar'

    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Added this lines to `proguard` has mentioned in this [post](http://android.amberfog.com/):

```
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-dontwarn com.android.volley.toolbox.**
```

I get the same error but now with some friendly output:

> Unexpected failure during lint analysis of BaseClient.java (this is a
>   bug in lint or one of the libraries it depends on)
>   TypeSystem.getUnannotatedType(TypeSystem.java:180)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:238)->TypeSystem.getParameterizedType(TypeSystem.java:261)->LookupEnvironment.createParameterizedType(LookupEnvironment.java:949) :app:validateExternalOverrideSigning :app:packageDevRelease FAILED

My BaseClient.java has some methods like this:

```
 public static <T extends Object, U extends Object> void executePostRequest(
               String url, 
               T requestPayload,
               Class<U> responseClass,
               Response.Listener<U> successListener,
               Response.ErrorListener errorListener){}
```

and

```
private static <T> BaseRequest.AuthRetryListener<T> createAuthRequestListener()
```

etc...

How can I make this work?
Thanks.

**EDIT 2:**
User **ajcpsoares** `-ignorewarnings` solution works. I'll leave this [link](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unresolvedlibraryclassmember) from ProGuard Troubleshooting docs. Also, since in my opinion this is a workaround instead of a solution I'll leave here the Android Open Source Project - Issue Tracker [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=202750) too.

Comment: I remember adding this to my top-level gradle file, maybe it helps a little: `tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:deprecation"}`

Comment: @m02ph3u5 thanks for your input. With that line I get logs like this: Warning:(75, 56) [deprecation] HttpStatus in org.apache.http has been deprecated, but I still get Unexpected failure during lint analysis... and it fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `-ignorewarnings` in your `proguard` file will it build successfully?

Comment: Well pointed! It works, but I guess it's more a workaround instead of a solution. I'll accept this answer 'cause in the end of the day it solves my problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Instead of including apache legacy library as a jar, try adding it as below:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
    ...
}
```

as described [here](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html#behavior-apache-http-client).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it doesn't work either :(
Using the .jar has the advantage that the HTTP classes are found by the IntelliJ, if I just use useLibrary I get ClassNotFound IDEA errors. It compiles and it works but it's a bit boring getting some classes with that red underline. Thanks anyway :)