# Proguard configuration makes APK broken

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard

i'm having an issue with `proguard`.

After adding `proguard`, i was getting warnings :

> Warning: com.actionbarsherlock.internal.ActionBarSherlockCompat: can't find referenced class com.actionbarsherlock.BuildConfig
>   Warning: com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewBehind: can't find referenced class com.slidingmenu.lib.R$id
>   Warning: com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewBehind: can't find referenced class com.slidingmenu.lib.R$id
>   Warning: com.slidingmenu.lib.CustomViewBehind: can't find referenced class com.slidingmenu.lib.R
>   Warning: okio.DeflaterSink: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Files
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.Path
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class java.nio.file.OpenOption
>   Warning: okio.Okio: can't find referenced class org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.IgnoreJRERequirement
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.ActivityCheckout$1: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.BaseInventory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.BaseInventory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull
>   Warning: org.solovyev.android.checkout.BaseInventory: can't find referenced class javax.annotation.Nonnull

And so on, 661 of them. After looking for response, i've ran into it, this is how it goes :

```
-dontwarn com.actionbarsherlock.**
-dontwarn org.solovyev.android.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn com.slidingmenu.**
```

I added this to my `proguard-android.txt` file, and it fixed an issue(*source for this approach : [Gradle Build Failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705589/gradle-build-failure)*)

But now, size of an .apk file decreased from 10mb to 5mb, and, as you can guess, it's not working, just crashes.

**Question:** what should i do to both : remove this warnings so .apk would build, and .apk that will be build would be working?

***EDIT:*** I've got the trace of error for release version and it has somethin to do with ormlite library, with this message :

> E/AndroidRuntime(16807): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:688)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:663)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.toAnnotationInstance(AnnotationAccess.java:641)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.getDeclaredAnnotation(AnnotationAccess.java:170)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at java.lang.reflect.Field.getAnnotation(Field.java:242)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.tojc.ormlite.android.annotation.OrmLiteAnnotationAccessor.getAnnotationColumnName(Unknown Source)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.tojc.ormlite.android.framework.ColumnInfo.(Unknown Source)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.tojc.ormlite.android.framework.TableInfo.(Unknown Source)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.tojc.ormlite.android.framework.MatcherController.addTableClass(Unknown Source)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.tojc.ormlite.android.framework.MatcherController.add(Unknown Source)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.test.kovla.provider.KovlaContentProvider.a(Unknown Source)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.test.kovla.provider.KovlaContentProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1737)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1712)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5437)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:5032)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4972)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:177)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1491)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5910)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: INTEGER
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:939)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(16807):    at libcore.reflect.AnnotationAccess.decodeValue(AnnotationAccess.java:685)

In fact, i've added `-keep class  com.tojc.** {*;}` to my `proguard-android.txt` and it doesn't help but only specified package right, it wasn't

> com.tojc.ormlite.android.annotation.OrmLiteAnnotationAccessor.getAnnotationColumnName(Unknown
>   Source)

before

**Edit:** If this is the list that was asked in comment :

```
repositories {
maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
jcenter()
}
```

Comment: Can you add a list of the repositories you added in your gradle file?

Comment: @Derp, i added it, if i understood correctly what you meant

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are using bunch of libraries. Please take a look over this [repository](https://github.com/krschultz/android-proguard-snippets). And use the progaurd configurations.

**EDIT**

As per your edit, you are probably having issues with the ormlite library.

Could you try this set of progaurd rules:

```
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
```

And I would insist on rebuilding the project once.