# Android Studio - Execution failed for task app:packageRelease

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio, execution, ioexception

I can't figure out what the problem is, i hope you can help me.

Error code:

> Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Failed to create 'C:\Users\AnjaWin7xD\AndroidStudioProjects\Ortung\app\app-release.apk'

Comment: where's the rest of the error log?

Comment: @ginomempin that's all what the console said

Comment: did you check the **Messages** and **Gradle Console** tabs? usually there's some error logs like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30705589/gradle-build-failure). and have you tried to "Invalidate Caches and Restart"? the only guess i have is that Android Studio can't write / doesn't have permission to write to that directory.

Comment: I think that was the reason, but i don't know. I did not get the error again since i wrote this question but i really think that the write permission was the error because i changed the project directory. Thank you for helping me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the destination folder for the app-release when generating the signed apk.That worked for me and I was able to generate the signed apk successfully.